# File Copy problem in C# the given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, winforms, file-copying

Here is my code to copy a file from one local location to another, and play it in winforms using windows media player.

I am getting an exception "The given path's format is not supported." during the file copy.

I can't seem to understand the issue. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

```
Value of exepath variable- "file:\C:\Users\HP\source\repos\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Debug"

Value of vdopath variable- "file:\C:\Users\HP\source\repos\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Debug\Folder1\Folder2\file"

Value of strtupPath- "C:\Users\HP\source\repos\TestProject\TestProject\bin"

Value of newvdopath- "C:\Users\HP\source\repos\TestProject\TestProject\bin\vdofile.mkv"
```

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using WMPLib;
   using System.IO;

   namespace TestProject
   {
       public partial class vdo_form_tmplt1 : Form
       {
           public vdo_form_tmplt1()
           {
              InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void PlayVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
            
               string exepath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

               string vdopath = System.IO.Path.Combine(exepath, "Folder1\\Folder2\\file");

               string strtupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);

               string newvdopath = System.IO.Path.Combine(strtupPath, "vdofile.mkv");

               System.IO.File.Copy(vdopath, newvdopath);

               axWindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit = true;
               axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = newvdopath;
           }

       }
   }
```

Comment: `string vdopath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Folder1\\Folder2\\file"); string newvdopath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "vdofile.mkv");`. Note that if your app is installed in `Program Files`, there a good change you cannot create a file in that path. Consider working with `Application.CommonAppDataPath`, `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` or its Roaming counterpart.

Comment: Also consider adding a `using System.IO;` directive on top of your class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using  Application.StartupPath instead of the exepath solved the problem :)